# Is my lottery machine fair?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I have a lottery machine with 100 balls inside.  Each trial, I draw 7 of the balls and record their numbers.  How do I determine if the results are biased or not?

Comment: This isn't a homework question, but one rephrased to eliminate distracting information.  I am 10 years out of practice on statistics so I may be going in the wrong direction.

Comment: What does the plot show? Why do use binomial distribution in here? If you ask about fairness, I'd imagine that you'd rather be talking about uniform distribution of the numbers drawn etc. Could you clarify?

Comment: I only obtained a minor in statistics, so, and memory is spotty.  I will research the uniform distribution in case that is a better way of estimating what the values should actually be.

Comment: Why can't you use the Chi-sq test of homogeneity based on an expected frequency of 7/100 (if sampling with replacement) or the combinatorial probability if sampling without replacement/

Comment: @AdamO The discussion following a [tentative answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/310694/919) explains the problem with that: it appears the chi-squared statistic may be well approximated by *some* chi-squared distribution, but how does one determine its degrees of freedom? To appreciate the problem, consider the extreme case where 100 balls are withdrawn (without replacement) each time: the distribution of counts of individual numbers will be perfectly uniform with no variation at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Uniform Probability Distribution with P=.10
After performing 20 trials:
Calculate the Chi^2 value by taking the Sum of (Observed-Estimated)^2.
Estimated is .10*20=2
Observed is the # of times each ball was drawn.
Degrees of Freedom for 20 trials, is 20-1=19.
Chi-Table value of .05, and DF=19 is 30.144

But, as this is drawing without replacement, this value needs to be offset by:
([Ball Count]-[Balls Drawn])/([Ball Count]-1)
30.144 * (100-7)/(100-1) = 32.089
So, an acceptable Chi^2 value will be less than 28.317.

Comment: This solution doesn't look quite correct, because the drawing is *without replacement.* This induces a dependence among the results. For instance, if 99 balls were drawn each time, we could perform an equivalent test by tallying the one ball not drawn. After 100 trials we would have a total of 100 spread among all 100 balls. Obviously these counts would not lead to a chi-squared distribution. Consequently, the chi-squared distribution would be inappropriate for your test. This shows that the dependence does affect the results, at least to some degree, when only 10 balls are drawn each time.

Comment: So what test would be more appropriate?  I started with Binomial & Tim pointed out that was incorrect.  And this answer is also not quite correct evidently.

Comment: Simulation suggests the test statistic should be multiplied by $(100-1)/(100-10)=1.1$ before comparing it to a $\chi^2(100-1)$ distribution. That lowers your critical value from 123 to 112.  I suspect an analysis of the hypergeometric log likelihood might support this result, but I haven't the time to carry it out.

Comment: Unfortunately goes mostly over my head.  Suppose I drew 7 balls instead, that would imply that I'd multiply my test statistic by (100-1)/(100-7) ?

Comment: Yes, that's the general pattern.

Comment: @whuber Ok, I've updated the answer.  Not marking as accepted because I'm still unsure.

Answer (score 0):

There are some papers devoted to this topic: [Tests of uniformity for sets of lotto numbers
by Harry Joe](http://doi.org/10.1016/0167-7152(93)90141-5) and [Statistical auditing and randomness test of lotto k/N-type games
by H.F.Coronel-Brizio et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2008.07.017). Be sure to run some power analysis, too, though.